# Custom HTML 5 Video Playback

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm creating a custom video playback to show off CAD animations of a product's features. I would like to have one viewing window, with three buttons to show the different product features. The video animations show the product front and center, then use exploding or zooming effects to show the features.

The tricky part is that I would like the video to play for a selected feature, ie feature 1. Then, when feature 2 is selected, I would like to have the video first play another video (feature 1 rewind), which shows the product returning to it's original state, then proceed in playing the next selected feature video (ie feature 2). I think the setup below might be correct, but am struggling on where to start with the javascript.

In sum, here is my desired playback functionality:

Select feature 1 button
Feature 1 video plays

Select feature 2 button
Feature 1 rewind video plays
Feature 2 video plays

Select feature 3 button
Feature 2 rewind video plays
Feature 3 video plays

Ideally, it wouldn't matter the order at which you selected the features, the above behavior would be the same (selected feature, video playback, next selected feature, rewind video playback, next feature video playback, etc.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--Here is the setup of video assets-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <button onclick="playFeature1()">Feature1</button>
  <button onclick="playFeature2()">Feature2</button>
  <button onclick="playFeature3()">Feature3</button>

  <br><br>
  <video id="feature1" width="420">
    <source src="feature1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

 <video id="feature1Rewind" width="420">
    <source src="feature1Rewind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature1Rewind.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <video id="feature2" width="420">
    <source src="feature2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

 <video id="feature2Rewind" width="420">
    <source src="feature2-Rewind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature2-Rewind.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <video id="feature3" width="420">
    <source src="feature3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature3.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

 <video id="feature3Rewind" width="420">
    <source src="feature3-Rewind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="feature3-Rewind.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>

</div>

<script>
//here is where I don't know how to approach the playback functionality.

var myVideo = document.getElementById("feature1");

function playFeature1() {

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll want to register a listened for the onEnded event for the rewind video then use that to load and start the forward video

Comment: Thank you! Could you possibly give an example of how that might look? I'm not sure how to trigger the rewind video for the most recently played video.